# Migrating app in IIS 6 to 7.0

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have web app written in .NET 2.0 hosted under IIS 6.0 with integrated authorization enabled. I moved this app to Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 with Windows auth enabled, and now I am getting this error. Any help?

> **Security Exception**
>
> **Description:** The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: An
>   operations error occurred.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**

```
[COMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.]
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +557
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +44
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +42
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne) +98
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne() +49


[SecurityException: Error authenticating user.]
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your new environment has a [trust level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx) other than FullTrust? What happens if you place this under the `<system.web>` section in the web.config?

```
<trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
```

Comment: no that did not help